# Ubuntu 13.10, Perl complaining about setting locale

Tags: ssh, locale, perl

I'm getting rather annoyed with Ubuntu 13.10. I need to go about fixing locales on my server, or else I see junk like this happening:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Most fixes online state that adding

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

to **.bashrc** and .bash_login should fix the problem.

Some mention that running the following from the commands:

```
$ sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
$ dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

should also help. I also tried rebooting the server on top of all the above.

It seems to work for when I'm SSH'ed into that server via terminal, but when I run remote deployment scripts from capistrano, I still get the Perl errors in my output.

I thought that's exactly what the exports in .bash_login should have fixed.

I even tried running

```
apt-get install language-pack-en-base
```

Nothing works!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes:

- System wide locale settings are stored in `/etc/default/locale`.
- It makes no sense to set all of LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE and LANG.

A cleaner solution is to let `/etc/default/locale` contain only

`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

and drop those entries in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: what do you mean, drop those entries in /etc/bash.bashrc?

Comment: @user44516: I mean the lines as described in the answer of josef.van.niekerk.

Answer (score 0):

I added the

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

snippet to /etc/bash.bashrc instead and that fixed the problem.

I doubt the call to locale-gen, dpkg-reconfigure and installing language-pack-en-base was necessary at all.

Answer (score -1):

I executed `locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` as root and it worked great.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9727654/3397659)